# Running Playwright tests in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, playwright

I am using Playwright for acceptance-driven tests. I am using the steps listed in the "installation" section to set it up locally and run the playwright tests. I would like to now run the tests in the Azure DevOps pipeline. How can I convert these [steps](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/intro) into appropriate tasks in the pipeline?

Comment: Please make an attempt to solve the problem yourself. If you encounter any issues, you're welcome to ask a specific question about how to correct it.

Comment: Have you looked at this page? https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/ci#azure-pipelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install and run using the following steps -

```
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: 'Build the E2E Test Application'
        inputs:
          command: build
          projects: $(workingDirectory)/MyProject.sln

      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: 'Install Browsers for Playwright'
        inputs:
          script: pwsh $(workingDirectory)/bin/Debug/net6.0/playwright.ps1 install

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: 'Run E2E Test'
        inputs:
          command: test
          projects: $(workingDirectory)/MyProject.sln
          arguments: '--filter "Category=MyFilteredTest"'
        env:
          MyEnvVar: $(myEnvVar)
```